# How to connect SQLite3 with Electron (Win10)

Tags: sqlite, electron

I'm trying to connect my Electron project with SQLite3 but I'm encountering an error that say's

> An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
>   Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [E:\Personal_Projects\myquiz\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]

I've followed these steps:
 1. install electron-rebuild (npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild)
 2. install sqlite3 using npm (npm install --save sqlite3)

Answer (score 1):

I've already found the solution just download and install the SDK 8.1 version.

Comment: which sdk version?